# multiple functions in php and getting results after each one

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a need for a script to fire off ajax requests in a sequential order.  I am building a user profile in our system.  Each ajax function builds a part of the profile.  After each part of the profile is done, the client will get a response, causing the script moves on to the next part. My goal is to show the progress as each part is built. Something like:

Building User.......done.

Building Email.....

And so on.

My problem here is that the ajax fires off all at once, which while expected is not sequential as needed.  I don't want to use `asych:false` because of the known caveats.  I have read about just putting the next ajax call in the success of the previous.  I am trying to avoid this because there are approx 15-20 calls I will have to make. That page would be ugly to read. I am trying the array approach as it seems the cleanest.

```
 $(function(){
 //array of functions
 var myArray = {'buildUser':'Building User','buildEmail':'Building Email'};

 $('#result').html("");

 //loop through array
 $.each(myArray, function(key, value) {
   //build "working" line
   $('#result').append("<div id="+key+">"+value+".....</div>");
   //send request to script
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",  
     url: "modules/userAdd/"+key+".php",
     data: "data="+data,
     success: function(result) {
       //replace "working" with "done"
       $('#'+key).html(value+".....Done");
     }
   })
 });
 });
```

Comment: I'm not too sure what your looking for, but this might be somewhere to start: http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Comment: That little paragraph right before you say "I don't even know where to start"? Start by turning that into code.

Comment: my question is should i attempt this with ajax? and if so, how do i get php POST vars into jquery?

Comment: relentless, i want to fire a function, then return a result, then fire another function, and so on.  in php if i put those functions in a script, i get all the functions run, then it returns the results...

Comment: You might be interesting in reading this: [Simple “Long Polling” example code?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/333664/367456)

Comment: re-wrote question...please remove hold?